# How to convert continuous number to datetime in python

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have load a matlab file and the time is a numpy array as show below:

```
array([  2.00301010e+09,   2.00301010e+09,   2.00301010e+09, ...,
     2.00912312e+09,   2.00912312e+09,   2.00912312e+09])
```

the values, for example the first one value in array means

```
2003010101.0 = 2003 (year) 01 (month)  01 (day)  01(hr)
```

How can I convert this continuous string (there is no space between) to datetime ? The questions before are always be sloved with the string saparated by "-" or " space " ". Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you try it without the separator? Also, it looks like a float, not a string.

Comment: This is a very odd way to store datetimes… but it can be parsed, either by doing some equally odd math, or by just converting to a string, removing the extraneous characters, and using the code from one of the other answers you've seen.

Comment: @roganjosh sorry I edit the question again.

Comment: @abarnert sorry I edit the question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your datetimes are, for some odd reason, encoded into a float, using a rule that looks something like this:

```
year * 1e6 + month * 1e4 + day * 1e2 + hour
```

So, you can decode it by just reversing that arithmetic. It might be cleaner to convert to an `int` first, to avoid any rounding issues. So, something like this:

```
ymdh = int(f)
y, mdh = divmod(ymdh, 1000000)
m, dh = divmod(mdh, 1000)
d, h = divmod(dh, 10)
```

You can, of course, make that more concise, but I wanted to make it as easy to understand as possible.

---

This has the (questionable) advantage that you can do it across the entire array at once:

```
ymdh = np.astype(f, np.int)
y, mdh = divmod(ymdh, 1000000)
m, dh = divmod(mdh, 1000)
d, h = divmod(dh, 10)
```

At the end, you've got four separate y, m, d, and h arrays; you can stack them up, or convert them into an array of structs, or just zip them to feed one by one to a normal Python function like `datetime.datetime`.

---

The other alternative is to convert it to a string and then use the same string date-parsing code you've found in other answers. The only trick here is that the numbers are in scientific format, so you have a few extra characters to get rid of. Something like this:

```
s = str(f).translate({c: None for c in '.E+'})
```

And now you've just got digits `YYYYMMDDHH`, which are easy.

Comment: Thanks ! This are indeed very clear explanation and solution :)